# How edit this SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I am quite new to SVG codes so I have a simple question.
On my page I need to use this svg code (of course with some styles, but thats not important now.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 40,0 40,100 0,60" />
    </svg>
```

Now it looks like this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL613.jpg)

But what I want:

Now it is the right side, which is longer, but I want the left side longer. I think it wont be hard to solve it, but I dont really know.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about technicalities use CSS: `transform: rotateX(180deg)`. [More about CSS transforms.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: rotateY worked for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, yeah, meant rotateY, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply switch the y coordinates of the last 2 data points.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 40,0 40,60 0,100" />
</svg>
```